# Getting data from MongoDB containing \r using Ruby fails

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have this MongoDB entry:

```
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('527d17c9cef2ea265b000027'), "quote"=>"PERSUADERS. Spurs. The kiddey clapped his persuaders\r  to his prad but the traps boned him; the highwayman\r  spurred his horse hard, but the officers seized him."}
```

When I use the Ruby driver to get this item, like so:

```
one = @db.collection('q').find_one({
    "_id" => BSON::ObjectId("527d17c9cef2ea265b000027")
})

puts one['quote']
```

I get only the output after the last `\r`

```
  spurred his horse hard, but the officers seized him.
```

How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, because you output it to the terminal. And `\r` is a control character, which means "go to the beginning of the line". So it prints something, then goes back and prints over.

Try this:

```
p one['quote']
```

or

```
puts one['quote'].inspect
```